# How do I fetch Ember-Data Values in an ArrayController using Ember-CLI?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm new to Ember.js and Ember-cli and have this rather basic problem of **not being able** to fetch a specific **model value** in my **ArrayController** and manipulate it here. I read several times through the ember.js doc about Controller Setup and Display of Models

http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/

but didn't find a solution to my case yet.

Here are my route, controller and model files:

```
    // /routes/sequences.js
import Ember from 'ember';

var SequencesRoute =  Ember.Route.extend({

        model: function() {
                return this.store.find('sequences');
        },
        setupController: function(controller, model) {
                this._super(controller, model);
        }
});


export default SequencesRoute;



// /controllers/sequences.js
import Ember from 'ember';

var SequencesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    init: function() {
                 this._super();
                 this.typeSeq();
    },
    i: 0,
    seqData: function(){
                var seq =  this.get('model.nts');
                return seq;
    }.property('model.nts'),
    len: function(){
                var slen = this.get('seqData');
                return slen.length;
    }.property('seqData'),
    typeSeq: function() {
                var tthis = this;
                var sequence = this.get('seqData');
                var lenn = this.get('len');
                 if (tthis.i <= lenn){
                        console.log(tthis.i);
                        console.log(sequence.substring(tthis.i,tthis.i+1));
                        tthis.i++;     
                        Ember.run.later(function(){
                                   tthis.typeSeq();
                                   }, 200
                        );             
                }
                else{
                        return false;
                }
        }
});

export default SequencesController;


// /models/sequences.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Genes = DS.Model.extend({
geneName: DS.attr('string'),
nts: DS.attr('string')
});

Genes.reopenClass({
FIXTURES: [
{
id: 1,
geneName: "Monoamine Oxidase A",
nts: "CTGCAGCGAGCGCGGGAAGCGGGACAGGGCCTAGAGTCACTTCTCCCCGCCCCTGACTGGCCCG"
},
{
id: 2,
geneName: "Monoamine Oxidase B",
nts: "TTTCTGCAGCGAGCGCGGGAAGCGGGACAGGGCCTAGAGTCACTTCTCCCCGC"
}
]
});

export default Genes;
```

Especially setting the property for *seqData* in my controller is not clear to me. What has exactly to be called to get my model data into the property? Will the setupController method in my router set a *model* property in my ArrayController embermagically, so I can fetch it via *model.nts* ? Right now, my ember app will build, but the var *sequence*, which is set in the *typeSeq* function, remains undefined.

Would be great to hear some answers from you or grab a link for a nice tutorial regarding this topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) sequence should be singular I believe, but maybe the other way works?

```
return this.store.find('sequence');
```

instead of

```
return this.store.find('sequences');
```

2) no need to do all that init/seqData stuff, the content property of the array controller will automatically be set to `this.store.find('sequence');` from your route model hook, you can just do this

```
len: function(){
    var length = [];
    this.get('content').forEach(function(item) {
           length.push(item.get('nts').length);
     });
    return length;
}.property('content'),
```

Comment: Do I see it right, that this will create a length array containing the length of all strings *nts* of the content object? How will I fetch e.g, the first of those lengthes later on? By using *this.get('len',1)* or something like *tthis.len[0]* inside my function *typeSeq()* ?

Comment: I had a second look and realized how to get the *length* value: Since your solution iterates over each item in content in the *forEach* loop, every string *nts* is fetched, and its *length* value just added to the earlier *length* value. Correct me, if I am wrong. I also implemented this similarly for my *seqData* property, because I had problems to fetch that data earlier as well. Now, it works!

Comment: changed it to array in my example instead of adding length of each string, you can access the first element later on by using this.get('len')[0];